# Replace screen content in Android with a ListActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, listactivity

To replace the screen content with different fragments I use this code

```
       getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new MainActivityTest())
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

What's the code to replace with a ListActitivy instead of a fragment?  I was using Intent, but I want the menu to still show since I have a navigation drawer built in.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigation drawer and action bar are part of the activity, by replacing it, they would be removed/recreated anyway. You can [show multiple activities inside another one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) but doing that is long deprecated. Use [`ListFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html).